# Craft warning: Tried to release a savepoint, but it does not exist

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, database, migration, mysql

I'm working on a plug-in for Craft 3. For this plug-in is a migration is needed.
When this migration runs and adds the entries, fields, and groups then the following warning occurs in the logs.

```
[warning][craft\db\mysql\Schema::releaseSavepoint] Tried to release a savepoint, but it does not exist: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT LEVEL2 does not exist
The SQL being executed was: RELEASE SAVEPOINT LEVEL2
```

This error means that the save point not exists.
I use Craft Pro 3.5.19.1 with PHP 7.4.12.

My question here is, what causes this warning?